# Pandas - convert rows to columns 'age_group' and assign values from another column 'registered_patients' to those corresponding columns

Tags: pandas, tabular

I want to convert rows to columns 'age_group' and assign values from another column 'registered_patients' to those corresponding columns.  All data is open source.

[image: tabulation_1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below worked for me.

```
df_ni_f.fillna('', inplace=True)

df_f = df_ni_f.groupby(['practice', 'lsoa_code', 'lsoa_name', 'la_code', 'la_name', 'sex_', 'mdm_decile', 'age_group'], as_index=False).agg({'registered_patients': ' '.join})
df_ff = df_f.pivot(index = ['practice', 'lsoa_code', 'lsoa_name', 'la_code', 'la_name', 'mdm_decile', 'sex_'], columns = ['age_group'], values = ['registered_patients'])

df_ff = pd.DataFrame(df_ff).reset_index()

df_ff.columns = df_ff.columns.get_level_values(0)

df_ff.head()
```

Comment: Some of the variables were changed in the final scripting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) to do a long-to-wide dataframe transformation :

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('db2020.csv')

df_wide=pd.pivot(df, index=['la_code','la_name', 'mdm_rank', 'sex'], columns = 'age_group',values = 'registered_patients').reset_index()

df_wide.fillna(0, inplace=True)

age_group_values = df['age_group'].drop_duplicates().tolist()

df_wide[age_group_values] = df_wide[age_group_values].astype(int)
```

##### >>> df_wide

[image]

Comment: Many thanks for your suggestion and script.  I previously attempted this and retried with your script, however, I continue to get the following error.  'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'.  For your script, this error occurs at the first line.

Comment: I have tried pivot, transpose and crosstabs without success.

Comment: It turned out to be a formatting issue earlier in the code.  Thank you for all your suggestions.